# Why are these two tuples in idris equal?

Tags: idris

I am reading [*Type driven development with Idris*](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris), and one of the exercises asks the reader to define a type `TupleVect`, such that a vector can be represented as:

```
TupleVect 2 ty = (ty, (ty, ()))
```

I solved it by defining the following type:

```
TupleVect : Nat -> Type -> Type
TupleVect Z ty = ()
TupleVect (S k) ty = (ty, TupleVect k ty)
```

The following test typechecks:

```
test : TupleVect 4 Nat
test = (1,2,3,4,())
```

My question is, why is `(1,2,3,4,()) == (1,(2,(3,(4,()))))`? I would have thought that the right hand side is a 2-tuple, consisting of an `Int` and another tuple.

Comment: could it be because `(x,y,z)` is syntactic sugar for `(x,(y,z))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking the documentation at http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#tuples, you can see that tuples are represented as nested pairs.

Hence `(x, y, z) == (x, (y, z))` for every `x`, `y`, `z`

Comment: Thanks, @marcosh :-)

Comment: you're welcome, I'm learning Idris, too. And answering questions is a nice way to learn

Comment: Why, though? In other languages like Haskell, (1, 2, 3) is not equal to (1, (2, 3)) and produces a type error. I guess it's not likely to cause problems, but it seems strange that Idris is permissive in this regard.